# Cursor-based Pagination in Facebook's Graph API

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, pagination, swift3

according to graphApi's documentation :

> **Cursor-based Pagination**
>
> Cursor-based pagination is the most efficient method of paging and should always be used where possible. A
>   cursor refers to a random string of characters which marks a specific
>   item in a list of data. Unless this item is deleted, the cursor will
>   always point to the same part of the list, but is be invalidated if an
>   item is removed. Therefore, your app shouldn't store any older cursors
>   or assume that they will still be valid.
>
> When reading an edge that supports cursor pagination, you will see the
>   following JSON response:

```
    {
  "data": [
     ... Endpoint data is here
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE=",
      "before": "NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    },
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&before=NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE="
  }
}
```

but i have no idea what's going on up here, anyone can point me on how we do **Cursor-based Pagination** here? i've done similar thing by passing the `Max_id` but in here its not the case

this is how i'm making my first call

```
    accessKey = "\(appID)|\(appSecret)"
    let connection = GraphRequestConnection()

    let request = GraphRequest.init(graphPath:"/myPageName/posts", parameters: [ "access_token" : accessKey, "fields" : "message,full_picture,created_time,story,type,permalink_url" , "limit": "10"], accessToken: nil, httpMethod: .GET, apiVersion: "2.8") 



        connection.add(request) { httpResponse, result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):

//FETCHED DATA HERE///

 case .failed(let error):
            print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
        }
 }
    connection.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Passing offset in parameter did the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
For this lets first understand Cursor paging with an example :
```

Let’s assume we want to paginate from the most recent user to the oldest user.When client request for the first time , suppose we select the first page through query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE team_id = %team_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT %limit
```

Where ***limit*** is equal to **limit plus one**, to fetch one more result than the count specified by the client. The extra result isn’t returned in the result set, but we use the ID of the value as the ***next_cursor***.

The response from the server would be:

```
{
   "users": [...],
   "next_cursor": "1234",  # the user id of the extra result
}
```

The client would then provide **next_cursor** as cursor in the second request.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE team_id = %team_id
AND id <= %cursor
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT %limit
```

> Coming back to Facebook Implementation : As the name suggests the ***next*** cursor will fetch you the next set of results and the ***previous*** cursor will fetch you the previous set of results.

If you still have problem understanding Cursors and why they are used you can check out this [article](https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack-1c1f644f8e12). The above example is quoted from the same.